# Is Nanachi able to ascend from the 6th layer again safely due to being a narehate?

Tags: made-in-abyss

I'm not sure if it's been covered but because Nanachi already has the blessing does that mean that as a narehate they can ascend without dying in a similar fashion to Mitty?

Wiki:
http://madeinabyss.wikia.com/wiki/Nanachi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nanachi is able to see Curse, so she is able to avoid it. You can also remember that she've established her hideout in zone free from Curse, which may mean she still **needs** to avoid it.

So, can she ascend from 6th layer again? Probably yes, if she can find zones free from Curse. Is she immune to Curse? Most probably - no, at least there were no apparent facts proving opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Well if she isn't immune to the curse, then she would fall to the effects at some time given her explanation of the curse being like the sheet because there is no way that there is always holes in the curse that she could exploit.

Perhaps she is just like the creatures in the abyss (given she is no longer classified as human) and is immune to the effects like them.
As for why she set up her house where she did it is possible it was for her experiments on the white and black whistles while she was trying to find a way to kill Mitty